# Is RavenDB Right for my Situation?

Tags: ravendb

I have an interesting situation where I'm near the end of an evaluation period for a RavenDB prototype for use with a project at our company. The reason it's interesting is that 99.99% of the time, I believe it fits Raven's sweet spot; it repeatedly queries for new data, often, and in small batches (< 1000 documents at a time).

However, we do have an initial load period, where we need to load two days' worth of data, which can be 3 million (or more) records in some cases.

A diagram might help:

[image]

It's the Transfer Service that is responsible for getting the correct data out of three production databases and storing it in RavenDB. The WCF service will query this data and make it available to its clients.

Once we do the initial load of millions of records/documents into RavenDB, we'll rarely have to do that again.

As an initial load test, on a machine with 4GB RAM and two processors, it took just over 23 minutes to read the initial data. In this case, it was only about 1.28 million records. I eliminated all async operations from this initial load, because I wanted each read to not be interfered with by other read operations. I found the best results this way.

[image]

I know it's not recommended, but to accomplish all this, I had to change settings that aren't recommended to be changed:

I had to increase the timeout:

```
documentStore.JsonRequestFactory.ConfigureRequest += (e, x) => ((HttpWebRequest)x.Request).Timeout = ravenTimeoutInMilliseconds;
```

In the Raven.Server.exe.config, I had to increase the page size (to int.MaxValue):

```
<add key="Raven/MaxPageSize" value="2147483647"/>
```

And in my retrieval methods, I had to use Take(int.MaxValue):

```
return session.Query<T>().Where(whereClause).Take(int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Remember this is all for that one-time, initial load. After that, it's many queries, quickly, and often. I should also note that each document is self-contained in RavenDB. There are no relationships to manage.

Knowing all this, is RavenDB a good fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've told us in the other answers comments, I believe the only good way to serve the wcf clients fast enough, is to actually store everything in memory, so just the way you do it now.

The question, if RavenDB is a good fit for that situation depends on whether your data model benefits in others way from the document oriented nature. So, in case you have dynamic data that would require some kind of EAV in a relational databases and lots of joins, then RavenDB will probably be a very good solution. However, if you just need something you can throw flat data in, then I would go with a relational database here. In terms of licensing costs and ease of use, you might also want to take a look at PostgreSql, as this is a really awesome database that comes completely free.

Comment: Thanks. I think we do benefit from Raven after the initial load, especially since we don't have to create tens of tables. It looks like we're going to use it, but it's not final yet.

Answer (score 2):

A good fit for *what*?

Full text search? Yes. Background aggregations (map/reduce ones)? Yes. Easy replication and sharding, say scaling? Yes...

Ad-hoc reporting? No. Support for probably thousands of third party tools? No...

If you're talking about performance, you probably want to look at Orens latest post on that. His numbers are quite similar to your ones: http://ayende.com/blog/154913/ravendb-amp-freedb-an-optimization-story

Comment: A good fit to serve as the data source for the WCF service. When the WCF service starts, it will need to load a lot of data from Raven. After that, it will get small amounts of data, every couple of minutes.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't realize that it needs to load the data every once the service starts. I just thought it was a one-time initial import and you were measuring performance metrics... sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your question, you need to "prep" the WCF web-service. To do this you read 1.2M docs from RavenDB (in about 23 mins) and hold them in memory, so the WCF service can then serve queries from them, is this right? Or am I missing something?

Why not get the WCF service to send it's queries to Raven one-at-a-time? I.e. for each query it gets from a Client, ask RavenDB to do the query for it?

Comment: That's correct. Your suggestion makes sense, and it may work. However, it's my understanding that we could have 12 clients hitting the service at once, each needing a fairly large amount of data. And with the read times we're seeing from Raven, that would cause an unacceptable delay.

Comment: Bob, why do you need all that data in-memory, I mean, you can't serve them to the clients in a single wcf request to the clients anyway, right? Do you actually need all of the data at the client side or just aggregations of them?

Comment: @BobHorn what type of queries will the clients be performing, how much data could they pull back per query? Are the client queries paged?

Comment: @DanielLang It's possible that we don't need all that data in memory, but that's the way version 1 is written. The WCF service won't return all of that data; each client will request its own portion of the data. And we can't use aggregates because the data is the source for charts.

Comment: @MattWarren The clients will be getting all documents with a simple where clause. I believe they can pull thousands of rows per query, but I'll check with the developer. No paging; the data is the source for charts.